# How to build Mongodb C driver without sudo

Tags: c, mongodb, build, driver

I am trying to build the C driver of MongoDB afetr I have build MongoDB and started it.
[On github](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver), I have found that I need root privileges to build it (I need to run it with sudo).
Is it possible to do it without sudo ?

Answer (score 1):

The instructions there state

```
make
sudo make install
```

So you ARE building as a normal user, but of course, *installing* it will require root privileges.

On a side note: using `DESTDIR` will install with a prefix the binaries don't know about. Software installed with `DESTDIR` is typically not runnable from the place it is installed. If you want to install in a non-standard location, do it at build-time (e.g. if the project uses *autotools*, pass a `--prefix=/home/foo/mytree` to `./configure`).

`DESTDIR` is only useful for creating packages. I use my own little package manager implemented in *perl* for managing installations in the `/usr/local` tree. It works by setting `DESTDIR` to `/usr/local/pkg/<product_name>` with `make install` and then symlinking everything to its correct location.

Comment: @bafla -- bullshit. the *building* step is the `make` command. that's what you were asking about. `make install` typically installs the result of `make` directly in your system. This requires root privileges. The `DESTDIR` facility is meant for *packages builders* to create archives of the tree, so thay can be installed later by a *package manager*.

Comment: @bafla Totally correct. What you found is a workaround, which will lead to future problems, since you will have to include `new_path/lib` to your `LIBDIR`s and `new_path/include` to your includes and more. Not installing to the default destinations is a step one should _really_ think about. More often than not it makes sense to talk to your local sysadmin to install to the `/usr/local/` tree, where locally compiled software belongs to as per FHS.

Comment: Thanks @MarkusWMahlberg. I will consider that

Comment: @bafla Another option would be to compile a static version of the library (not sure if that will be easy) and link your program statically.

Answer (score -1):

I have just now realised that I can change the installation directory while installing using `DESTDIR` as a destination directory.
In my case it would look like this: `make DESTDIR=new_path install`

Comment: Although you're answering your *own* question, it's not the answer to your question. You are confusing *building* with *installing*.